# Homestead with Symfony 2.8 - Class Redis not found

Tags: php, redis, homestead, symfony-2.8, predis

First of all, thanks for helping me!

I have this strange problem that I can't figure out how to resolve it.I am using homestead with Symfony 2.8, also, I am using redis-bundle... and I get this error "Class Redis not found.." when I try to do a composer update, the application is not even starting.

Comment: i think you register redis-bundle in appkernel before composer update

Comment: It's registered.

Comment: that's why i am asking, first unregister it and then update composer.